# How can my outer container right align all inner elements?

Tags: css

I am trying to right align all my containers' (`div`) inner elements. Each element should sit one above each other (as opposed to inline/next to each other).

Do you know how my container can make the `video`, `img` and `audio` elements right align?

```css
  .container {
    text-align: right;
  }

  .container > * {
    display: block; // so every child element is on a new line
    max-width: 150px;
  }
```

```html
<h4>All the below should be right aligned</h4>
<div class="container">
     <p>A p element</p>
     <a href="">An anchor element</a>
     <span>A span element</span>
     <label>A label element</label>
     <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
     <video controls="controls" poster="https://via.placeholder.com/150"></video>
     <audio controls="controls"><source src="http://www.archive.org/download/1001_questions_grammar_2009_librivox/1001grammar_01_hathaway_128kb.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
     <hr>
</div>
```

Comment: One solution is to give the child elements the following settings: `float: right; clear: both`

Comment: another sol is that giving img,video,audio{margin:0 0 0 auto}

Comment: text-align align only the text and not the block elements

Answer (score 1):

Try using flexbox with a vertical direction by setting `flex-direction` to `column`, and then align them to the right by setting `align-items` to `flex-end`.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.container > * {
  max-width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<h4>All the below should be right aligned</h4>
<div class="container">
     <p>A p element</p>
     <a href="">An anchor element</a>
     <span>A span element</span>
     <label>A label element</label>
     <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
     <video controls="controls" poster="https://via.placeholder.com/150"></video>
     <audio controls="controls"><source src="http://www.archive.org/download/1001_questions_grammar_2009_librivox/1001grammar_01_hathaway_128kb.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
     <hr>
</div>
```